# Haskell Yahoo Finance Command Line Tool

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments, yahoo, haskell-platform, yahoo-finance

I am trying to use [this module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/Finance-Quote-Yahoo/0.7.0/doc/html/Finance-Quote-Yahoo.html) to create a command line tool that will grab a quote from yahoo finance for a symbol. When I try to compile I receive this error.

```
Couldn't match expected type `[t0]'
                with actual type `IO
                                    (Maybe (Map (QuoteSymbol, QuoteField) QuoteValue))'
    In the return type of a call of `getQuote'
    In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
        q <- getQuote [arg] ["s", "l1", "c"]
    In the expression:
      do { q <- getQuote [arg] ["s", "l1", ....];
           case q of {
             Nothing -> error "symbol not found"
             Just m -> m } }
```

I am just starting to learn haskell, which is an incredibly different but powerful language, and I can not quite figure out what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated and I would also appreciate any feedback on if I'm doing this the "haskell" way and if not any improvements I can make. Thanks!

```
module Main where

import Finance.Quote.Yahoo
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Map
import System( getArgs )
import System.Console.GetOpt
import Data.Maybe ( fromMaybe )

data Options = Options
    { optVerbose     :: Bool
    , optShowVersion :: Bool
    , optOutput      :: Maybe FilePath
    , optInput       :: Maybe FilePath
    , optLibDirs     :: [FilePath]
    , optSymbol      :: String
    } deriving Show

defaultOptions    = Options
    { optVerbose     = False
    , optShowVersion = False
    , optOutput      = Nothing
    , optInput       = Nothing
    , optLibDirs     = []
    , optSymbol      = "YHOO"
    }

options :: [OptDescr (Options -> Options)]
options =
    [ Option ['v']     ["verbose"]
        (NoArg (\ opts -> opts { optVerbose = True }))
        "chatty output on stderr"
    , Option ['V','?'] ["version"]
        (NoArg (\ opts -> opts { optShowVersion = True }))
        "show version number"
    , Option ['o']     ["output"]
        (OptArg ((\ f opts -> opts { optOutput = Just f }) . fromMaybe "output")
        "FILE")
        "output FILE"
    , Option ['c']     []
        (OptArg ((\ f opts -> opts { optInput = Just f }) . fromMaybe "input")
        "FILE")
        "input FILE"
    , Option ['L']     ["libdir"]
        (ReqArg (\ d opts -> opts { optLibDirs = optLibDirs opts ++ [d] }) "DIR")
        "library directory"
    , Option ['s']     ["symbol"]
        (ReqArg (\ s opts -> opts { optSymbol = getSymbol s }) "SYMBOL")
        "symbol SYMBOL"
    ]

compilerOpts :: [String] -> IO (Options, [String])
compilerOpts argv =
    case getOpt Permute options argv of
        (o,n,[]  ) -> return (foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o, n)
        (_,_,errs) -> ioError (userError (concat errs ++ usageInfo header options))
    where header = "Usage: ic [OPTION...] files..."

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    compilerOpts args

getSymbol :: String -> String
getSymbol arg = do 
  q <- getQuote [arg] ["s", "l1", "c"] 
  case q of
    Nothing -> error "symbol not found"
    Just m -> m
```

Comment: Are you sure that you pasted exactly same code that you are running? Please take a look at `main` function.

Comment: Don't format blocks of code by manually adding `<pre><code>` tags, that can't cope with html characters in the code. Use the `{}` button in the editor instead, or manually indent your code by four spaces.

Comment: this should be uploaded to github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that `getSymbol` has no business in the definition of `options`, since it is an `IO` action as we can see from the fact that it uses `getQuote`:

```
getQuote :: [QuoteSymbol] 
         -> [QuoteField]   
         -> IO (Maybe (Map (QuoteSymbol, QuoteField) QuoteValue))
```

So where you say `optSymbol =  getSymbol s` you should just put the string s.  The crucial line should certainly read

```
(ReqArg (\ s opts -> opts { optSymbol =  s }) "SYMBOL")
```

not

```
(ReqArg (\ s opts -> opts { optSymbol =  getSymbol s }) "SYMBOL")
```

At the moment you are just parsing arguments. What you do with the `optSymbol` string -- e.g. go to Yahoo to find out about it via `getSymbol` -- belongs in `main` or some preliminary action you need to define.  Here is a module that typechecks, it barely does anything, acting like this:

```
-- $ ./yahoo -s STD.F  -- Standard Chartered?
-- STD.F c -0.396 - -1.99%
-- STD.F l1 19.492
-- STD.F s STD.F

module Main where

import Finance.Quote.Yahoo
import Data.Time.Calendar
import Data.Map
import Prelude
import qualified Prelude
import System.Environment( getArgs )
import System.Console.GetOpt
import Data.Maybe ( fromMaybe )
import System.IO.Unsafe

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    (options, strs) <- compilerOpts args
    whatIDoWithTheUsersOptions options strs

-- This is not doing much with all this user input ...
whatIDoWithTheUsersOptions :: Options -> [String] -> IO ()
whatIDoWithTheUsersOptions options strs = do
    blather <- getSymbol $ optSymbol options
    putStrLn blather

getSymbol :: String ->  IO String
getSymbol arg =   do
  q <- getQuote [arg] ["s", "l1", "c"] 
  case q of
    Nothing -> return $ "symbol " ++ arg ++ " not found"
    Just m -> return $ unlines $ Prelude.map helper (toList m)
 where helper ((a,b), c) = unwords [a,b,c]


data Options = Options
    { optVerbose     :: Bool
    , optShowVersion :: Bool
    , optOutput      :: Maybe FilePath
    , optInput       :: Maybe FilePath
    , optLibDirs     :: [FilePath]
    , optSymbol      :: String
    } deriving Show

defaultOptions    = Options
    { optVerbose     = False
    , optShowVersion = False
    , optOutput      = Nothing
    , optInput       = Nothing
    , optLibDirs     = []
    , optSymbol      = "YHOO"
    }

options :: [OptDescr (Options -> Options)]
options =
    [ Option ['v']     ["verbose"]
        (NoArg (\ opts -> opts { optVerbose = True }))
        "chatty output on stderr"
    , Option ['V','?'] ["version"]
        (NoArg (\ opts -> opts { optShowVersion = True }))
        "show version number"
    , Option ['o']     ["output"]
        (OptArg ((\ f opts -> opts { optOutput = Just f }) . fromMaybe "output")
        "FILE")
        "output FILE"
    , Option ['c']     []
        (OptArg ((\ f opts -> opts { optInput = Just f }) . fromMaybe "input")
        "FILE")
        "input FILE"
    , Option ['L']     ["libdir"]
        (ReqArg (\ d opts -> opts { optLibDirs = optLibDirs opts ++ [d] }) "DIR")
        "library directory"
    , Option ['s']     ["symbol"]
        (ReqArg (\ s opts -> opts { optSymbol =  s }) "SYMBOL")
        "symbol SYMBOL"
    ]

compilerOpts :: [String] -> IO (Options, [String])
compilerOpts argv =
    case getOpt Permute options argv of
        (o,n,[]  ) -> return (Prelude.foldl (flip id) defaultOptions o, n)
        (_,_,errs) -> ioError (userError (concat errs ++ usageInfo header options))
    where header = "Usage: ic [OPTION...] files..."
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
getSymbol :: String -> String
getSymbol arg = do 
  q <- getQuote [arg] ["s", "l1", "c"] 
  case q of
    Nothing -> error "symbol not found"
    Just m -> m
```

It should probably be:

```
getSymbol :: String -> IO String
getSymbol arg = do 
  q <- getQuote [arg] ["s", "l1", "c"] 
  case q of
    Nothing -> fail "symbol not found"
    Just m -> return m
```

Note I have changed the type signature and the final two lines. (Since I have changed the type of `getSymbol`, you will have to use the result differently wherever you call it.)

A partial explanation:

You are using `do` syntax, which results in a monadic value. The return type of `getSymbol` was `String`, which is the same as `[Char]`. Lists are monads, so this is fine.

But then you call `getQuote` on the right of a `<-`, which results in an `IO` value. `IO` is monadic, but `IO` is not the same as lists, so we have an error. (You have to use the same monad on the right hand side of a `<-` as the `do` block results in.)

**Edit:** The above code change isn't going to be enough. `m` has type `Map (QuoteSymbol, QuoteField) QuoteValue` which obviously isn't the same as `String`, so you want to compute something from `m` instead of returning it directly. I don't know exactly what you want to do here.

Also, you're using `getSymbol` in your option parsing code. It's better if your save the *input* to `getSymbol` in your `Options`, and call `getSymbol` later with that value, after you have processed the command line options. (Otherwise you might contact Yahoo's servers only to discover that a different command line option is wrong and throw the answer away. Not to mention that the `optSymbol` field can't hold `IO`.)